# Options basics needs to be cleared

Tags: options

I'm not clear for the terminology of options and the mechanics of it. Any help is appreciated. For example the following statement:

> European call option of Apple stock with maturity 1 year and strike
>   price $15. The option is trading at 13 dollars.

- Is it correct to say that the premium is $13 for this call option?
- When is the premium paid, when the buyer buys the option or at maturity?
- Can the holder of the option exercise it whenever he wants or should wait for the maturity?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regarding question 3.  American options CAN be exercised before expiry/maturity.  It is a different question than "SHOULD" they wait until maturity.

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes the option premium is $13. Premium just means how much you have to pay for the option
2. The premium is paid upfront, so whenever the buyer enters the contract/buys the option
3. European options can only be exercised at maturity. An American option is the type of option that can be exercised before maturity at any time. A Bermudan option can be exercised at a discrete set of dates before maturity.

Last point is credit to @DaneelOlivaw

Comment: “An **American option** is the type of option that can be exercised before maturity _at any time_”. A **Bermudan option** can be exercised at a discrete set of dates before maturity.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw yeah that's definitely correct. I was trying to be ambiguous since it seemed like the OP didn't need extra details. Thanks!

Comment: I think $13 is spot price of apple stock and premium would be something different. $13 premium when the strike is $15 looks suspicious.